# Finding Chromecast with VLC

Tags: 20.04, vlc, chromecast

I am using VLC 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to play a video on my Chromecast 3. However, when I open the renderer menu it appears empty -- not even "Local", one option I had before upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. See image below.

[image]

How can I get VLC to search for my Chromecast, so I can cast video?